# rich:panelMenu blinks instead of collapsing on first click

Tags: java, richfaces

I'm facing some problems with rich:panelMenu, my code is the following:

```
<rich:panelMenu style="width:200px" itemMode="ajax" groupMode="ajax"
            topGroupExpandedRightIcon="chevronUp" expandSingle="false" 
            topGroupCollapsedRightIcon="chevronDown"
            groupExpandedLeftIcon="triangleUp" groupCollapsedLeftIcon="triangleDown"
            itemLeftIcon="disc" activeItem="#{navigator.menuItemSelected.id}">

    <rich:panelMenuGroup label="Principal" rendered="true" expanded="true">
        <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{msg.BANDEJA_OFICINA}" name="bandejaOficina" rendered="true" action="#{navigator.goToView('bandejaOficina',true)}">
        </rich:panelMenuItem>
    </rich:panelMenuGroup>

    <rich:panelMenuGroup label="Administracion" rendered="#{navigator.admin}" expanded="true">
        <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{msg.SQL}" name="SQL" rendered="true" action="#{navigator.goToView('sqlQuerys',false)}">
        </rich:panelMenuItem>

        <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{msg.USUARIOS}" name="USUARIOS" rendered="true" action="#{navigator.goToView('mgrUsuarios',true)}">
        </rich:panelMenuItem>

        <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{msg.OFICINAS}" name="OFICINAS" rendered="true" action="#{navigator.goToView('mgrOficinas',true)}">
        </rich:panelMenuItem>

        <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{msg.SYSPARM}" name="SYSPARM" rendered="true" action="#{navigator.goToView('mgrSysParam',true)}">
        </rich:panelMenuItem>

    </rich:panelMenuGroup>
</rich:panelMenu>
```

Menu works as intended, but in the view, when you click on panelMenuGroup (Principal or Administracion) the menu blinks, and then you need to click it again for the menu to collapse, any help is welcome!

Comment: What's your RichFaces and browser version?

Comment: RichFaces 4.3.7, tested in Firefox v38.0.1, IE v10.0.9200.16798, and Chrome v43.0.2357.81 m.

Comment: any update on this..? xD